# What is the alphanumeric id in a reddit URL?

Tags: python, url, slug, reddit

What is the `7n5lu` in the reddit URL

> http://www.reddit.com/r/reddit.com/comments/7n5lu/man_can_fly_if_you_watch_one_video_in_2

...and how is it generated?

Update:
@Gerald, I initially thought this is some obfuscation of the id. It is just doing the conversion from integer to a more compact representation. I am thinking, why is this being done? why not use the original integer itself!!

```
>>> to36(4000)
'334'
>>> to36(4001)
'335'
```

Comment: If you use numbers with letters, the final string is shorter. e.g.:

    to36(9) == '9'
    to36(10) == 'a'

Answer (score 28):

The reddit source code [is available](https://github.com/reddit/reddit)! Here is what I found for generating that string:

```
def to_base(q, alphabet):
    if q < 0: raise ValueError, "must supply a positive integer"
    l = len(alphabet)
    converted = []
    while q != 0:
        q, r = divmod(q, l)
        converted.insert(0, alphabet[r])
    return "".join(converted) or '0'

def to36(q):
    return to_base(q, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

and elsewhere, under the "Link" class:

```
@property
def _id36(self):
    return to36(self._id)
```

Comment: Note they have a micro-bug: the zero case assumes zero is "0".  The last line should end with "or alphabet[0]".

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a unique id for the thread. It's most likely used to find the thread in the database.

Answer (score 0):

It is an integer, just in base 36. The id is generated sequentially. For example, the comment right after id `89` is id `8a`, etc. Given this, you don't need any other information from the URL.

Comments, posts, messages, users, and subreddits can in theory have the same ID and count up. You can differentiate them by their "fullname" which is the type of thing, an underscore, and then an underscore.

`t1` is a comment, `t2` is a user, `t3` is a submission, `t4` is a message, `t5` is a subreddit, `t6` is an award, `ModAction` is a moderator action, `ModmailConversation` is a modmail conversation, etc.

See [the API documentation](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

Little remark.

It is not sufficient for this example but usually appending to lists

```
a = []
for i in range(NNN): a.append(i)
a.reverse()
```

really more efficient than inserting at head.

```
a = []
for i in range(NNN): a.insert(0,i)
```

.