# 1-1 mappings for id obfuscation

Tags: language-agnostic, url, encryption, hash

I'm using sequential ids as primary keys and there are cases where I don't want those ids to be visible to users, for example I might want to avoid urls like ?invoice_id=1234 that allow users to guess how many invoices the system as a whole is issuing.

I could add a database field with a GUID or something conjured up from hash functions, random strings and/or numeric base conversions, but schemes of that kind have three issues that I find annoying:

1. Having to allocate the extra database field. I know I could use the GUID as my primary key, but my auto-increment integer PK's are the right thing for most purposes, and I don't want to change that.
2. Having to think about the possibility of hash/GUID collisions. I give my full assent to all the arguments about GUID collisions being as likely as spontaneous combustion or whatever, but disregarding exceptional cases because they're exceptional goes against everything else I've been taught, and it continues to bother me even when I know I should be more bothered about other things.
3. I don't know how to safely trim hash-based identifiers, so even if my private ids are 16 or 32 bits, I'm stuck with 128 bit generated identifiers that are a nuisance in urls.

I'm interested in 1-1 mappings of an id range, stretchable or shrinkable so that for example 16-bit ids are mapped to 16 bit ids, 32 bit ids mapped to 32 bit ids, etc, and that would stop somebody from trying to guess the total number of ids allocated or the rate of id allocation over a period.

For example, if my user ids are 16 bit integers (0..65535), then an example of a transformation that somewhat obfuscates the id allocation is the function f(x) = (x mult 1001) mod 65536. The internal id sequence of 1, 2, 3 becomes the public id sequence of 1001, 2002, 3003. With a further layer of obfuscation from base conversion, for example to base 36, the sequence becomes 'rt', '1jm', '2bf'. When the system gets a request to the url ?userid=2bf, it converts from base 36 to get 3003 and it applies the inverse transformation  g(x) = (x mult 1113) mod 65536 to get back to the internal id=3.

A scheme of that kind is enough to stop casual observation by casual users, but it's easily solvable by someone who's interested enough to try to puzzle it through. Can anyone suggest something that's a bit stronger, but is easily implementable in say PHP without special libraries? This is getting close to a roll-your-own encryption scheme, so maybe there is a proper encryption algorithm that's widely available and has the stretchability property mentioned above?

EDIT: Stepping back a little bit, some discussion at [codinghorror](https://blog.codinghorror.com/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids/) about choosing from three kinds of keys - surrogate (guid-based), surrogate (integer-based), natural. In those terms, I'm trying to hide an integer surrogate key from users but I'm looking for something shrinkable that makes urls that aren't too long, which I don't know how to do with the standard 128-bit GUID. Sometimes, as commenter Princess suggests below, the issue can be sidestepped with a natural key.

EDIT 2/SUMMARY:

- Given the constraints of the question I asked (stretchability, reversibility, ease of implementation), the most suitable solution so far seems to be the XOR-based obfuscation suggested by Someone and Breton.
- It would be irresponsible of me to assume that I can achieve anything more than obfuscation/security by obscurity. The knowledge that it's an integer sequence is probably a crib that any competent attacker would be able to take advantage of.
- I've given some more thought to the idea of the extra database field. One advantage of the extra field is that it makes it a lot more straightforward for future programmers who are trying to familiarise themselves with the system by looking at the database. Otherwise they'd have to dig through the source code (or documentation, ahem) to work out how a request to a given url is resolved to a given record in the database.
- If I allow the extra database field, then some of the other assumptions in the question become irrelevant (for example the transformation doesn't need to be reversible). That becomes a different question, so I'll leave it there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find that simple XOR encryption is best suited for URL obfuscation. You can continue using whatever serial number you are using without change. Further XOR encryption doesn't increase the length of source string. If your text is 22 bytes, the encrypted string will be 22 bytes too. It's not easy enough as to be guessed like rot 13 but not heavy weight like DSE/RSA.

Search the net for PHP XOR encryption to find some implementation. The first one I found is [here](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/xor-encryption.htm).

Comment: It's super easy to figure out the key phrase if the user gets his hands on more than one message.

Answer (score 3):

I've toyed with this sort of thing myself, in my amateurish way, and arrived at a kind of kooky number scrambling algorithm, involving mixed radices. Basically I have a function that maps a number between 0-N to another number in the 0-N range. For URLS I then map that number to a couple of english words. (words are easier to remember).

A simplified version of what I do, without mixed radices: You have a number that is 32 bits, so ahead of time, have a passkey which is 32-bits long, and XOR the passkey with your input number. Then shuffle the bits around in a determinate reordering. (possibly based on your passkey).

The nice thing about this is

1. No collisions, as long as you shuffle and xor the same way each time
2. No need to store the obfuscated keys in the database
3. Still use your ordered IDS internally, since you can reverse the obfuscation
4. You can repeat the operation several times to get more obfuscated results.

if you're up for the mixed radix version, it's basically the same, except that I add the steps of converting the input to a mixed raddix number, using the maximum range's prime factors as the digit's bases. Then I shuffle the digits around, keeping the bases with the digits, and turn it back into a standard integer.

Answer (score 2):

You might find it useful to revisit the idea of using a GUID, because you can construct GUIDs in a way that isn't subject to collision.

Check out the [Wikipedia page on GUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID) - the "Type 1" algorithm uses both the MAC address of the PC, and the current date/time as inputs. This guarantees that collisions are simply impossible.

Alternatively, if you create a GUID column in your database as an alternative-key (keep using your auto-increment primary keys), define it as unique. Then, if your GUID generation approach does give a duplicate, you'll get an appropriate error on insert that you can handle.

Comment: Good points. I'll read that article and see if there are types of GUID that suit my purposes, and try to amend the question so that the terms 'hash' and 'GUID' are used less interchangeably.

Answer (score 2):

I saw this question yesterday: [how reddit generates an alphanum id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410485/)

I think it's a reasonably good method (and particularily clever)

it uses Python

```
def to_base(q, alphabet):
    if q < 0: raise ValueError, "must supply a positive integer"
    l = len(alphabet)
    converted = []
    while q != 0:
        q, r = divmod(q, l)
        converted.insert(0, alphabet[r])
    return "".join(converted) or '0'

def to36(q):
    return to_base(q, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a char(10) field to your order table... call it 'order_number'.

After you create a new order, randomly generate an integer from 1...9999999999.  Check to see if it exists in the database under 'order_number'.  If not, update your latest row with this value.  If it does exist, pick another number at random.

Use 'order_number' for publicly viewable URLs, maybe always padded with zeros.

There's a race condition concern for when two threads attempt to add the same number at the same time... you could do a table lock if you were really concerned, but that's a big hammer.  Add a second check after updating, re-select to ensure it's unique.  Call recursively until you get a unique entry.  Dwell for a random number of milliseconds between calls, and use the current time as a seed for the random number generator.

Swiped from [here](http://code.google.com/p/substruct/source/browse/trunk/plugins/substruct/app/models/order.rb#207).

**UPDATED** As with using the GUID aproach described by Bevan, if the column is constrained as unique, then you don't have to sweat it.  I guess this is no different that using a GUID, except that the customer and Customer Service will have an easier time referring to the order.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a much simpler way. Say you want to map N digits, pseudorandomly to N digits. you find the next highest prime from N, and you make your function

```
prandmap(x) return x * nextPrime(N) % N
```

this will produce a function that repeats (or has a period) every N, no number is produced twice until x=N+1. It always starts at 0, but is pseudorandom thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly thing encrypting/decrypting query string data is a bad approach to this problem. The easiest solution is sending data using POST instead of GET. If users are clicking on links with querystring data, you have to resort to some [javascript hacks](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum83/6115.htm) to send data by POST (keep accessibility in mind for users with Javascript turned off). This doesn't prevent users from viewing source, but at the very least it keeps sensitive from being indexed by search engines, assuming the data you're trying to hide really that sensitive in the first place.

Another approach is to use a natural unique key. For example, if you're issuing invoices to customers on a monthly basis, then "yyyyMM[customerID]" uniquely identifies a particular invoice for a particular user.

Comment: Good point about natural keys. Using POST instead of GET - the kind of attacker/noseyparker I have in mind would be capable of interpreting HTML source and sniffing HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, personally, I would start off by working with whatever standard encryption library is available (I'm a Java programmer, but I assume, say, a basic AES encryption library must be available for PHP):

- on the database, just key things as you normally would
- whenever you need to transmit a key to/from a client, use a fairly strong, standard encryption system (e.g. AES) to convert the key to/from a string of garbage. As your plain text, use a (say) 128-byte buffer containing: a (say) 4-byte key, 60 random bytes, and then a 64-byte medium-quality hash of the previous 64 bytes (see Numerical Recipes for an example)-- obviously when you receive such a string, you decrypt it then check if the hash matches before hitting the DB. If you're being a bit more paranoid, send an AES-encrypted buffer of random bytes with your key in an arbitrary position, plus a secure hash of that buffer as a separate parameter. The first option is probably a reasonable tradeoff between performance and security for your purposes, though, especially when combined with other security measures.
- the day that you're processing so many invoices a second that AES encrypting them in transit is too performance expensive, go out and buy yourself a big fat server with lots of CPUs to celebrate.

Also, if you want to hide that the variable is an invoice ID, you might consider calling it something other than "invoice_id".