# Ruby's "next" implementation in Python

Tags: python

If Python has an implementation of Ruby's `next` method? I mean something what works exactly the same as in Ruby, so if I type e.g. `"z".next` it will return `"aa"` (instead of just next sign in ascii table), `"az".next` will return `"ba"` and so on.

Comment: I assume you mean `"z".next` and `"az".next`.

Comment: No, python doesn't have this.  You'd need to build it yourself...

Comment: Generally speaking, if you ask for the exact same functionality from another language (when it's not common among many languages like functions/methods or loops), it means that you're not adopting the mindset of the language. You should step back and ask the question, "What am I trying to accomplish at a higher level?" Python may have different idiomatic ways of doing *that*.

Comment: This seems like a simple base-26 increment.

Comment: @erip That's what I thought at first, but I don't think it is. I would think that in base 26, `a == 0`, `b == 1`, etc., and after `z == 25`, the next number would be `ba == 26` (not `aa`, which would be the same as `a`).

Comment: @smarx Ah, excellent observation!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a built-in method for this in Python. A similar question was asked on [How can I get the next string, in alphanumeric ordering, in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932506/how-can-i-get-the-next-string-in-alphanumeric-ordering-in-python) and the accepted answer gives a solution.